# Why it is possible to show a base64 encoded PNG with an "image/jpeg" data URL?

Tags: image, browser, base64, data-uri

Here's as an example of a base64 encoded PNG data URL (using "image/png" data type, of course):

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAASCAYAAABWzo5XAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMTczbp9jAAAA1UlEQVQ4T62SsQ0CMQxFUzAEA1BQMgIlI1zJCIxAT0HJCBSUlFdQMAQlJWOE78hnObYDIuJLTzr/+/5FkpRz/guh2UM9pLQBWzDXvgVacG4lngncAH08QFgGLcEL0LAX34ROHCBcGaRLiEH+meAMXDhESBlkS3bVrh6KEZetQbOk7FmjmL5M40rKTmQSEJVdeXlCDtcSmgRkz4Ro32Zo+pK7+g7LqqEYjduBjsrzT6Mavl3xhzIJcXDkEBHfTl3WfNln8ARhyQR0sDkX6iU0ewjN38npDdYczGIKuRnZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

I noticed that (in Firefox and Chrome) things work even if data type is set to "image/jpeg" (and leaving all the rest untouched) like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAASCAYAAABWzo5XAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAHBhaW50Lm5ldCA0LjAuMTczbp9jAAAA1UlEQVQ4T62SsQ0CMQxFUzAEA1BQMgIlI1zJCIxAT0HJCBSUlFdQMAQlJWOE78hnObYDIuJLTzr/+/5FkpRz/guh2UM9pLQBWzDXvgVacG4lngncAH08QFgGLcEL0LAX34ROHCBcGaRLiEH+meAMXDhESBlkS3bVrh6KEZetQbOk7FmjmL5M40rKTmQSEJVdeXlCDtcSmgRkz4Ro32Zo+pK7+g7LqqEYjduBjsrzT6Mavl3xhzIJcXDkEBHfTl3WfNln8ARhyQR0sDkX6iU0ewjN38npDdYczGIKuRnZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

But... Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're both using the image handling subsystem, which ignores the mime type and just goes with the actual format of the image.

Specifically, most browsers will translate the viewing of an image into the viewing of an HTML webpage with an `<img>` tag in them. Since servers lie and browsers are supposed to be able to show even badly-configured websites, the part of the browser that deals with images will in most cases completely ignore any extensions or MIME types. There was no point programming in an exception for `data:` URIs.

Comment: Well, yeah, it does make sense. Thank you, accepted